# Opengl Obj with multiple textures. Jpg texture don't display

Tags: opengl, c++, assimp

Hi i have problem with jpg textures. DDS is working good but jpg is not.
This is my function to load JPG texture. In debuger i see that this works but
i dont see anything.

```
char * a =(char *) path.c_str();
text = ilutGLLoadImage(a);

return text;
```

My function to bind texture. It works for dds but not for jpg. My second question is that
if i have n-textures for object should can i use only one uniform?

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[0]);
glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
```

EDIT Ok my problem is with vertex, fragment shadder

Comment: What library are you using to load the JPG? There's no support for JPG in plain OpenGL.

Comment: @Anko he is using DevIL, it works nicely with OpenGL. Anyway he is not checking for errors so it's hard to guess the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are loading the image twice, `ilutGLLoadImage` actually loads the image to the GPU memory (it's a wrapper above OpenGL functions), you are also calling `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, text);` and `glTexImage2D` after that, that should trigger an error because `text` is already used, you only need to use one of them; if you use the  .

When binding your Texture you need to make sure that you are actually binding the correct texture and texture unit. Which is actually hard to tell from your code.

To explain the issue I just notice that you always bind `0` in the `glUniform` function. Each texture unit have an id strating from [0, n]. So in order to correctly bind your textures, first bind the texture object to the correct texture unit. Then pass the texture unit to the shader using `glUniform`, this unit will have the texture that was bind.

```
//Step 1 This essentially binds  Textures[0] to TextureUnit0
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // This is texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Textures[0]); // This binds the texture object to the texture unit.

// This passes the texture unit (not the object) to the shader.
glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);

 // This will pass texture unit 1 (you should bind a texture object 
glUniform1i(TextureID, 1);like you did for the first unit.
```

Make sure to understand the difference between [texture units and texture objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866904/need-help-understanding-the-differences-and-relationship-between-glactivetexture).

The reason this is a confusing terminology, is that because of legacy that openGL carries. The designers wanted to support old code. So they couldn't add another param to the texture functions (couldn't change the OpenGL Interface).

Comment: Hmm. I am newbe in this. How should i knew that i  bind the correct texture and texture unit?

Comment: @Luffy I hope it's clear now.

Comment: ok now i understand. My only problem left is that devil dont want to init.